# plot using gnuplot or python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have a txt file with trajectories. How can I plot the column 3 by gnuplot and have vertical line to separate trajectories.

```
#indexes:         0
   1        -0.375E+04         0.382E+01        
   2        -0.375E+04         0.332E+01        
   3        -0.376E+04         0.353E+01        
#indexes:        1
   1        -0.735E+04         0.093E+01
   2        -0.735E+04         0.096E+01
   3        -0.735E+04         0.082E+01
   4        -0.735E+04         0.094E+01
#indexes:         2
   1        -0.835E+04         0.401E+01
   2        -0.035E+04         0.438E+01
   3        -0.365E+04         0.438E+01
```

I have many  indexes.

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example shell script that works with your example data.
It assumes the data is in a file `data`, creates a 2nd tmp file `/tmp/data2`,
and an image `/tmp/data.png`.

```
#!/bin/bash
max=$(awk <data '
 !/^#indexes/{ if($3+0>max)max = $3 }
 END {print max}')

awk <data >/tmp/data2 -vmax="$max" '
  /^#indexes/ {printf "%s %s\n",i,max; next}
              { i++; }'

gnuplot <<\!
set terminal png
set output "/tmp/data.png"
plot "data" using 3 with lines linetype rgb "red",\
 "/tmp/data2" using 1:2 with impulse linetype rgb "blue"
!
# eg: display /tmp/data.png
```

The first awk finds the max value of the 3rd field. The 2nd awk
creates a data line "i max" for each "#indexes" line, where `i` counts
the number of data lines, i.e. the x axis values for the blue vertical
lines.

Comment: Very neat that you did the parsing in bash